# How to make item selectable in recycler view and use it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have followed android developer documents to create the recycler view. But now I would like to make the item selectable.

Currently have created `itemAdapter.kt`

```
class ItemAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val dataset: List<Mode>,
    private val itemClickListener: MainActivity
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder.

    class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
    }

    /**
     * Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    /**
     * Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.textView.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringResourceId)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(item) //here we are sending the mode object using interface
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(mode: Mode)
    }

}
```

Then there is data file called `Modes.kt`

```
class Modes {
    fun loadModes(): List<Mode> {
        return listOf(
            Mode(R.string.height),
            Mode(R.string.hleveldistance),
        )
    }
}
```

Then there is model file called `Model.kt`

```
data class Mode(val stringResourceId: Int)
```

How do I get the selected item for my function in the mainactivity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //private var etCommand: EditText? = null
    private var tvPalaute: TextView? = null
    private val modes = Modes().loadModes()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize modes

 val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.adapter = ItemAdapter(this, modes, this)
        // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        //val etCommand: EditText = findViewById(R.id.et_command)
        val etSubmit: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)
        val etMeasure: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_measure)

        tvPalaute = findViewById(R.id.tvPalaute)


        etSubmit.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Haetaan laite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                openActivityForResult()
        }

        etMeasure.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Aloitetaan mittaus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                openMeasureActivityForResult()
        }
    }

    fun onItemClick(mode: Mode) {
//openMeasureActivityForResult(mode) // update method to receive mode as an argument
        Log.d(mode.code, "mode code")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mode is $mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun openMeasureActivityForResult(mode: Mode) {
        val measureAction = "com.app.app.m"
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = measureAction
        //val selectedMode = mode?.Id
        //var mode = modes[selectedMode!!]
        intent.putExtra("Mode", mode?.code)
        Log.d(intent.toString(), "intent")
        intent.putExtra("AppName", "Example App")
        //if (!String.toString().isNullOrEmpty(Device))
        //{
          //  intent.putExtra("Device", Device);
        //}
        measureLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
```

This is my current state of the code. What should the openmeasureactivity function get as it parameter? And is the code looking allright since itemadapter is not in use now. And does the selected item look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user `interface` to pass `objects` to the `activity`.

Create an `interface` `ItemClickListener` with a method named `onItemClick` with a `parameter` of type, whatever you want to receive in your `activity`. For here use `Mode`

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(mode: Mode)
}
```

In your `activity` or `fragment` implement this `interface`, and override the `onItemClick` method to perform any operations on the selected `Mode` object.

```
class MainActivity : ItemClickListener {

    override fun onItemClick(mode: Mode) {
        openMeasureActivityForResult(mode) // update method to receive mode as an argument
    }

    private fun openMeasureActivityForResult(mode: Mode) { //use mode here
        val measureAction = "com.app.app.m"
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = measureAction
        //var mode = modes[SelectedMode] <-- here the selected value
        //intent.putExtra("Mode", mode.Code); <-- also here
        intent.putExtra("AppName", "Example App")
        //if (!String.toString().isNullOrEmpty(Device))
        //{
          //  intent.putExtra("Device", Device);
        //}
        measureLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

Change `ItemAdapter` to accept `ItemClickListener` in its `constructor`

```
class ItemAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val dataset: List<Mode>,
    private val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {


}
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder()` set a click listener to the `holder`s `itemView` and pass `mode` object using the `itemClickListener`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.textView.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringResourceId)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(item) //here we are sending the mode object using interface
        }
    }
```

In `activity` or `fragment`, when you create `adapter` just pass the instance of `ItemClickListener`'s interface, we can pass it using `this` as we've already implemented it above.

```
val adapter = ItemAdapter(
    context,
    modeList,
    this 
)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but not sure if I did it correctly. I updated my answer. It seems that itemAdapter is not used anywhere now. And openmeasure activity function wants some kind of parameter

Comment: And I have button that starts that intent.

Comment: Also it gives this when clicking item: ```js
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 31888
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2131689515
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:3766)
        at com.example.app.MainActivity.openMeasureActivityForResult(MainActivity.kt:71)
        at com.example.app.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.kt:62)
        at com.example.app.adapter.ItemAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-0(ItemAdapter.kt:50)
```

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, are you sure the index you are accessing is in the list?

Comment: I got to show now the selected mode and id in the toast (updated my question), and i think it might be going also to the intent but I am getting resultcode 0 so im not sure if my mode.code is correct or incorrect when its returning the resultcode 0 and wont get any data out

Comment: Seems that the selected value isn't going to the intent and results to the resultcode 0. ``` D/Bundle[{Mode=null, AppName=Example App, Device=1280}]: extras```

Comment: I got it working now. :) Just made global variable and then onClick function did this `selectedMode = mode.code`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I made an interface for the on click, then in your fragment you override this fun with whatever you want to do.

```kotlin
// Here I add --> val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener
class MovieAdapter(
private val movies: List<Mode>, 
val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val binding = ItemMovieBinding.bind(itemView)

        fun bind(mode: Mode) {
            // Here we set the setOnClickListener
            itemView.setOnClickListener {itemClickListener.onClick(mode)}
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context
        // R.layout.item_mode --> change to yor layout
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_mode, parent, false)
        )
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the list
     */
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = movies.size

    /**
     * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(movies[position])
    }
}
// The interface we can use in the fragment
interface ItemClickListener{
    fun onClick(mode: Mode)
}
```

then you can use the interface in your fragment:

```kotlin
override fun onClick(mode: Mode) {
   // here you can use the object
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood this how does it work