# Bottom Sheet for multiple items inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a posts feed that looks like Twitter. Each item in that feed has a button that when clicked should open up a bottom sheet. The feed uses the RecyclerView layout and the paging library. My question is how do I go about implementing bottom sheet for each individual item dynamically so that when a user clicks on the button a menu is displayed that gives the option to report the user of that post, copy that post's link, etc. I'm not sure how to go about dynamically creating a bottom sheet for each individual item and giving dynamic data to each individual bottom sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a single `bottomsheet` for this to achieve, and you can pass the data for each of `list` items, on which you want to show this `bottomsheet` on.

Let our `Post` `data class` looks like this

```
data class Post (
    val userId: Int,
    val link: String
)
```

Create an interface to pass the `Post` data from our `recyclerView` to our `fragment`.

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(post: Post)
}
```

Implement this `interface` inside of the `fragment`

```
class TestFragment: Fragment(R.layout.test_fragment), ItemClickListener {
    override onItemClick(post: Post) {
         // will open bottomsheet from here
    }
}
```

Now pass the reference of `ItemClickListener` to the `recyclerView`'s adapter and when the user clicks on the item, then call the `onItemClick` method of the `listener` and pass the `Post` of the clicked view. You can read a more detailed answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72146425/11983124)

After we've received the `post` inside the `fragment`, we can now create our `bottomsheet` dialog and show it

```
private fun showBottomSheetDialog(
    post: Post
) {
    val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireActivity())
    val bottomSheetBinding = BottomSheetPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.root, false)

    bottomSheetBinding.apply {
        tvShare.setOnClickListener {
            sharePostLink(post.link) // share your post link from here
        }
        
        tvReport.setOnClickListener {
            repostUser(post.userId) // report user
        }
    }

    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetBinding.root) 
    bottomSheetDialog.show()
}
```

From inside of `overrided` `onItemClick` method call this `showBottomSheetDialog` method.

```
override onItemClick(post: Post) {
    showBottomSheetDialog(post)
}
```

You can do the same if you are creating a `BottomSheetDialogFragement` instead of `BottomSheetDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Things you have to do to achieve this is pretty simple

1. Pass a lambda function with an argument that accepts the data item which the RV holds to the constructor of your RecyclerView adapter.
2. Inside `onBindViewHolder` you can set onClickListeners to your list items views
3. Now wherever you initialize your recycler view you can define what has to be done when a user clicks via lambda functions.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831977/13049473

You can then retrieve whatever data you need from RV to your activity/fragment and then you can use it to display your bottomsheet

Comment: How do you set up the bottom sheet in that context though?

Comment: I have everything set up, I just don't know how to incorporate bottom sheet into the recyclerview